# Filtering Queryset and designing correct urls.py and templates in Django

Tags: python, html, django, models

I am designing a video rendering kids website.

- The app has parent *categories* for eg: Cartoons, Education shows etc. Each *category* has multiple *posts* such as Jungle_book,Duck_tales etc for cartoons.
- Each *post* has multiple *episodes*.
- I am using generic views(listview, Detailview) for views.

Here are my **Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from personal.models import Post


class cartoons_post(models.Model):
    category= models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
    thumbnail=models.ImageField()
    date=models.DateField()


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})


class post_episode(models.Model):
    post_id= models.ForeignKey(cartoons_post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
    thumbnail=models.ImageField()
    date=models.DateField()
    video=models.FileField()


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"id": self.id})
```

Here is my **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from cartoons.models import cartoons_post,post_episode
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = [ 

                url(r'^$', login_required(ListView.as_view(
                                queryset=cartoons_post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:10],
                                template_name="cartoons/cartoons.html"))),
                url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', login_required(ListView.as_view(
                                queryset=post_episode.objects.filter(post_id=1).order_by("-date"),
                                template_name="cartoons/post.html"))),
                url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+\d+)$',login_required(DetailView.as_view(
                                    model = post_episode,
                                    template_name="cartoons/post_episode.html"))),
            ]
```

Here are my three **templates**

**cartoons.html**

```html
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %} 
{% for cartoons_post in object_list %} 
 <a href="/cartoons/{{cartoons_post.id}}"> <img src= "{{cartoons_post.thumbnail.url}}" width="200" height="220"> </a>
{% endfor %}      
{% endblock %}
```

**post.html**

```html
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
{% for post_episode in object_list %} 
 <a href="/cartoons/{{post_episode.id}}"> <img src= "{{post_episode.thumbnail.url}}" width="200" height="220"> </a>
{% endfor %} 
{% endblock %}
```

**post_episode.html**

```html
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block content %}
 <div class="container-fluid_cartoons">
 <h3>{{post_episode.title}}</h3>
 <video width="850" height="500" controls>
   <source src="{{post_episdoe.video.url}}" type="video/mp4">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
 </div> 
{% endblock %}
```

**Issues**
 - Only cartoons.html is working fine.

- Once I click on an individual post the relevant post.html shows all the episode uploaded rather than episodes pertaining to individual post only.
- Once I click on an episode, nothing happens.

Comment: You should use @python_2_unicode_compitable rather than custom both __unicode__ and __str__

Answer (score 0):

You should consider creating `views.py` file rather than using generic views in urls.py. I think issue is with following line

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$',login_required(ListView.as_view(queryset=post_episode.objects.filter(post_id=1).order_by("-date"),template_name="cartoons/post.html"))),
```

Here, If my guess is correct, you are trying to pass `id` of post model from url to view. But to make ListView accept url kwargs (post_id) you have to write another view in views.py. Maybe something like below.

```
class EpisodeListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'cartoons/post.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return post_episode.objects.filter(post_id=self.kwargs['post_id']).order_by("-date")
```

Then route a url to that view:

```
from <yourapp.views> import EpisodeListView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
url(r'^episodes/(?P<pk>\d+)$',login_required(EpisodeListView.as_view())
```